# Android webview app not installed through the directory

Tags: android, webview

I am a newbie on android. I have Created a WebView app.
When I test my application through an emulator, it works fine.

The app is also installed when I select the

> Run -> Run 'app' -> and then select my connected device (Not Emulator).

But when I go to my project folder `/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/xyz.apk`

or under the folder `/app/build/outputs/apk/release/xyz.apk`

then when I select to install then I receive an error that is App is not installed.

Any suggestion where I am doing mistakes.

I also generated the signed apk through *Build-> Generate signed Bundle or Apk* option. But not getting any success.

Any help is really appreciated.

This is my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="com.example.test">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"
            tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

        <application
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="Test"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:name=".MyApp">
            <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                </intent-filter>

            </activity>

            <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        </application>       
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Can you please share your manifest file.

Comment: @Jay I added my manifest file on my question.

Comment: uninstall previously installed app. Create new one by disabling instant run and then try to install it.

Comment: @Aks In which device you are testing this app?? Android version of that device?

Answer (score 0):

It is done through simplest process. Go to Build -> click on Rebuild Project.
That's it. I got this solution. And I am installing this apk to my cellphone(Real device)